# Vue Component does not render...Renders as empty HTML comment

Tags: c#, vue.js, vue-component, asp.net-core-2.0

Problem:

- Vue component renders on screen as `<!---->`

Setup:

- Application is in C# Core 2.0
- Vue version 2.5.16
- Use gulp to copy static js files to /wwwroot 
  `gulp.src('./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/dist/'))`
- Call to load Vue in HTML 
  `<script src="~/dist/vue.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>`
- I have four components. Two use string literal templates and two use `<template>`. Of the later, only one displays.  
  `<template id="paging-template"></template>
  <template id="modal-template"></template>`
  `Vue.component('modal',{ template:'#modal-template'});
  Vue.component('paging',{ template:'#paging-template'});`

Modal is called with `<modal></modal>` and Paging with `<paging></paging>`.

Modal displays properly. Paging displays as `<!---->` but using the Vue debugger addon in Chrome I can see the model and everything for the Paging component is there.

What am I missing?

Edit:
 [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/52qv7Lx4/)

This css is not mine, just the default on the Vue template they provide

Comment: Can you display the syntax for your index.html and application.vue or main vue page.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for us to determine what the problem is.

Comment: I do not have any .vue files. My Vue model is instantiated in a regular .js file loaded to the page. If not enough information was provided could you please specify what information you are looking for?

Comment: Link to JSFiddle provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with your example(All of them are visible in the console tab of the browser):

Your class binding syntax is incorrect. All instances where you are trying to bind classes as follows:

```
v-bind:class="'disabled': previousDisabled"
```

Should be updated to:

```
v-bind:class="{disabled: previousDisabled}"
```

`isNumber` is not a method. It can be replaced with `!Number.isNaN(`

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/52qv7Lx4/1/)

Comment: My hero...I had spent so much time staring at the code I had become blind to these obvious mistakes. And sadly my console wasn't showing any errors.